# Is there any way of adding an image to a bar in a chart in ExtJS via the highlight property?

Tags: extjs, sprite, highlight

I want to add an icon in the column/bar onMouseOver and was wondering if highlight already supported that. The docs say you can add whatever Sprite has available to the highlight object ( http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar-cfg-highlight however even in the Sprite definition ( http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.draw.Sprite ) there's no mention of how to do this beyond setting the type to image.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs there doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this. The Sprite class supports `addCls` and `removeCls` methods though, you could try setting a className to the sprite element and see whether a background image for an element with that className works. Otherwise the sprite element for the bar chart would have to be redefined into something more complex that takes images as a component.

In future, you should post over on the [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/index.php) as you will get a quicker response.

Comment: I've had hit and miss experiences with the Sencha forums. Thanks for the answer, I'll give that a try and rate your answer if it works.